# ASP.NET core CORS headers not showing

Tags: asp.net, cors, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-middleware

I have a File - New Project - MVC Web Application in my VS 2015 running on netcoreapp1.0 with imports: "dotnet5.6" and "portable-net45+win8", which has the standard Values api that returns an array of strings.

In my Startup.cs, I've only added the line:

```
services.AddCors(opt => opt.AddPolicy("test", p => p.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().Build()));
```

to the ConfigureServices method before **services.AddMvc()**.
And to the Configure method, I've added **app.UseCors("test")** to use the policy:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    app.UseCors("test");

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

When I call this api in Postman, I get these response headers:

```
Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8
Date →Tue, 23 Aug 2016 08:35:19 GMT
Persistent-Auth →true
Server →Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
X-Powered-By →ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles →=?UTF-8?B?XFxiaWp0amVzLmJlXGRhdGFcaG9tZWRpclxuaWxzZ1x2aXN1YWwgc3R1ZGlvIDIwMTVcUHJvamVjdHNcV2ViQXBwbGljYXRpb240XHNyY1xXZWJBcHBsaWNhdGlvbjRcYXBpXHZhbHVlcw==?=
```

When I call it from our SharePoint site (for example, can be any website, just to make sure it's not from localhost) using JQuery:

```
$.ajax({url: 'http://localhost:60079/api/values', success: function(data){ console.log(data); }, error: function(err){ console.error(err); } });
```

I get these response headers (in Dutch):

```
Antwoord    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
Server  Kestrel
X-SourceFiles   =?UTF-8?B?XFxiaWp0amVzLmJlXGRhdGFcaG9tZWRpclxuaWxzZ1x2aXN1YWwgc3R1ZGlvIDIwMTVcUHJvamVjdHNcV2ViQXBwbGljYXRpb240XHNyY1xXZWJBcHBsaWNhdGlvbjRcYXBpXHZhbHVlcw==?=
Persistent-Auth true
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
WWW-Authenticate    Negotiate oRswGaADCgEAoxIEEAEAAACO2brFdOYicQAAAAA=
Date    Tue, 23 Aug 2016 09:04:48 GMT
```

There is no preflight request sent, in the IE 11 network monitor, there is only 1 request sent.

As seen in the headers, the CORS headers are not being added.

I've also tried this in an ASP.NET Core RC1 application that I have, this doesn't show any of the headers either.

I Think the CORS are working, because I can access the api from any Origin. 
If I use 'WithOrigin()' however, and for example don't add the SharePoint, it still allows me to call the URL.
I've also tested this in Fiddler, Chrome and Firefox, none of them show the headers.

How can I get the headers to be added in ASP.NET Core and secure my API's with the WithOrigins()?

Comment: I'm currently experiencing the same issue with my .NET Core 2.0 app.  Did you ever figure out how to get the headers to be added to the response?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I try every answer found for this question but nothing worked for me. So, since "the right way" do not work I decided to do it manually:

```
[HttpOptions]
public IActionResult YourMethod()
{
    Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS,POST");
    Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    return Ok();
}
```